# A derivation of Ampere's Law. How did Ampere figure it out?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

As we know, Ampere's Law equates the path integral of the magnetic field and the current * vacuum permeability. But how did Ampere figure this out? I understand the path integral portion of ampere's law; that makes sense. But how was he able to equate the line integral of the magnetic field to the current times the vacuum permeability? I have only taken math up to calculus III. Also, I just want the derivation without the added changing electric field term in Maxwell's equation.

Comment: Historically he didn't. All his work was related to forces between conducting wires. The notion of a magnetic field mediating the currents and forces is the product of later developments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law

Comment: Alright then. Then whoever added to ampere's law, how did they know to equate the line integral to the current * vacuum permeability?

Comment: You can measure magnetic field strength, for example by how much force (or torque) it exerts on a permanent magnet. So do that near a conducting wire, then change the current in the wire and do it again. Now you know the field is proportional to the current.

Comment: Would this be better on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know who did this first, but it's pretty straightforward so I'd imagine it was Ampere himself.

You can measure magnetic field strength, for example by how much force (or torque) it exerts on a permanent magnet. So do that near a conducting wire, then change the current in the wire and do it again. Now you know the field is proportional to the current.

Finding that the constant of proportioanality is equal to the permeability of the material around the sensing magnet would be an immediate next step.